# how to check liblua version at compile time?

Tags: c, lua, c-preprocessor

working on some code that should compile against both liblua5.0 and liblua5.1, for example i need to call `lua_openlibs(luaState);` in 5.0 and `luaL_openlibs(luaState);` in 5.1 (`lua` vs `luaL`), how can i check at compile time if i'm compiling against 5.0 or 5.1?

libcurl has a neat preprocessor for this called `CURL_AT_LEAST_VERSION`, in libcurl i could write

```
#if CURL_AT_LEAST_VERSION(5, 1, 0)
// lua >=5.1-specific code
luaL_openlibs(luaState);
#else
// lua < 5.1-specific code
lua_openlibs(luaState);
#endif
```

how can i achieve something similar with liblua?

Comment: I think, this question better be directed at Lua support.

Comment: @SergeyA "Lua support"? Lua is an open-source project, not a commercial product. SO is a perfectly reasonable place to ask a question about using it.

Comment: Have you checked the Lua header files for any kind of version macro?

Comment: @duskwuff they still should have a wiki, a mail list or something else, don't they?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes i checked the 5.0 header, and none was present (well i found `#define LUA_VERSION "Lua 5.0.3"` but that doesn't seem helpful) - but 5.1+ has it, as explained by @Duskwuff below :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lua 5.1 and later define the macro `LUA_VERSION_NUM` to a decimal representation of the version number, e.g. `501` for Lua 5.1. You can compare against it with a macro, e.g.

```
#if defined(LUA_VERSION_NUM) && LUA_VERSION_NUM >= 510
lua 5.1 code
#else
older version code
#endif
```

Comment: btw seems it's called `LUA_VERSION_NUM` in 5.2, and.. seems it's not defined in 5.0 - i found this in 5.0 but it doesn't look particularly helpful: `#define LUA_VERSION "Lua 5.0.3"`

Comment: - it's `LUA_VERSION_NUM`, not `LUA_VERSION_NUMBER`, edited that, but worse is: it's not defined in 5.0 (at least not 5.0.3), but still i can work with this, if it's not defined i'll just treat it as 5.0-specific, i don't need 4.X support anyway, thank you :)

Comment: Whoops, my typo. You could wrap this in `#ifdef LUA_VERSION_NUM` as a safeguard I suppose?

Comment: indeed, i will do that :)